# no tag "cyrillic"?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

The [post on Mar 9, 2023](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/19051/12337) needs tags like "cyrillic", "russian-empire", "russian". Why are there no such tags yet? At least, "cyrillic". It could draw attention of those who know something in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the case for it is not yet strong, I just added a new tag of [cyrillic](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cyrillic) to three questions including the one that you referenced.